# Return rows if they exist in multiple JOIN table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

**UPDATE:** Can someone help with this?

**I edited my sql query to working example but still getting all rows from `post_comment_response_approval`. We should not return any rows for those who do not exist in that `team_member_manager` table (even if they have a record in post_comment_response_approval) --> see table examples**

I am writing an sql query within Postgres 12.

The query should return rows for all members in that `post_comment_response` table, and it should not return any rows for those who do not exist in that `team_member_manager` table (even if they have a record in `post_comment_response_approval`).

```
    SELECT
        post_comment_response.*,
        SELECT JSON_AGG(approvals_inner) FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    pcra.team_member_id,
                    pcra.note
                FROM post_comment_response_approval pcra
            ) AS approvals_inner
        ) AS approvals,
        count(*) OVER() AS total_count
    FROM post_comment_response
    LEFT JOIN post_comment ON post_comment.id = post_comment_response.post_comment_id
    JOIN post ON post.id = post_comment.post_id
    JOIN team_member ON team_member.id = post.team_member_id
    JOIN team_member_manager tmm ON (tmm.managing_team_member_id = team_member.id AND tmm.managed_team_member_id = post.team_member_id)
    WHERE team_member.team_id = 91
```

I want to geather results using mutiple joins but on adding `JOIN team_member_manager tmm ON (tmm.managing_team_member_id = team_member.id AND tmm.managed_team_member_id = post.team_member_id)` I do not get any results..

`managing_team_member_id` is the one with defined value (`91`)

`managed_team_member_id` value I want to get by `JOIN`ing **post_comment → post** and getting `post.team_member_id`.

I was careful with syntax and I do not know why do I not get any results..

The tables are below:

`post_comment_response` table:

| id | post_comment_id | comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1173 | Hello World |

`post_comment_response_approval` table:

| id | post_comment_response_id | team_member_id | approved | note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 54 | 1 | 60735 | true | This one should be listed |
| 70 | 1 | 666 | true | This should not |

`post_comment` table:

| id | post_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1173 | 652 |

`post` table:

| id | message_id | team_member_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 652 | 110 | 60735 |

`team_member_manager` table:

| id | managing_team_member_id | managed_team_member_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 55 | 68893 | 60735 |

`team_member` table:

| id | team_id | member_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 68893 | 91 | 1 |

I can not get my head around of what I am doing wrong? Can someone please help?

Comment: I see that you put much effort into explaining this, but I still don't understand. You want to show all post_comment_responses, except for those made by the manager(s) of team 91? Why do you join the managers table? When looking for rows that don't exist, use `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN`.

Comment: Thanks for replay. Actually, I want to display all responses that can be found in team_member_manager table and managing_team_member_id is currently auth user (which has team_id of 91) and the other managed_team_member_id which I am getting from post.team_member_id.  I posted all tables data so everyone can check that they are present but I do not still get any rows returned. Can you maybe show me an example you are suggesting me to implement? Thanks @ThorstenKettner

Comment: I updated my answer following your example, still no results. Thanks @ThorstenKettner

Comment: Please see my answer. Here is a short explanation added: You have `tmm.managing_team_member_id = team_member.id AND tmm.managed_team_member_id = post.team_member_id`. But as `team_member.id = post.team_member_id` (which we see in the `ON` clause in the join before), this is merely: `tmm.managing_team_member_id =  tmm.managed_team_member_id` which is not at all what you want.

Answer (score 1):

From your explanation I think your mistake is that you check the posting member's team ID, when you want to the check the posting member's manager's team ID. This means you must join again to the team_member table to see the manager's data.

```
SELECT
  pcr.*,
  COUNT(*) OVER() AS total_count
FROM post_comment_response pcr
JOIN post_comment pc ON pc.id = pcr.post_comment_id
JOIN post p ON p.id = pc.post_id
JOIN team_member tm ON tm.id = p.team_member_id
JOIN team_member_manager tmm ON tmm.managed_team_member_id = tm.id
JOIN team_member mgr ON mgr.id = tmm.managing_team_member_id
WHERE mgr.team_id = 91;
```

I think this query makes the relations very clear. A post is posted by a member, that member has a manager, and the manager themselves is also a member in the member table.

As you don't need any data from the posting member, though, you can remove this join from the query:

```
SELECT
  pcr.*,
  COUNT(*) OVER() AS total_count
FROM post_comment_response pcr
JOIN post_comment pc ON pc.id = pcr.post_comment_id
JOIN post p ON p.id = pc.post_id
JOIN team_member_manager tmm ON tmm.managed_team_member_id = p.team_member_id
JOIN team_member mgr ON mgr.id = tmm.managing_team_member_id
WHERE mgr.team_id = 91;
```

The same with an `IN` clause:

```
SELECT
  pcr.*,
  COUNT(*) OVER() AS total_count
FROM post_comment_response pcr
WHERE post_comment_id IN
(
  SELECT pc.id
  FROM post_comment pc
  JOIN post p ON p.id = pc.post_id
  JOIN team_member_manager tmm ON tmm.managed_team_member_id = p.team_member_id
  JOIN team_member mgr ON mgr.id = tmm.managing_team_member_id
  WHERE mgr.team_id = 91
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you explanation and for provided example. I've not figure this out so far: tmm.managing_team_member_id =  tmm.managed_team_member_id are the same.. I will use one of the approaches.  Thank you for you help! @ThorstenKettner

Comment: Actually one mistake.. Query is returning one row with managed_team_member_id that is not existing in team_member_manager table.. It should return just rows that are defined in that table (even if they exist in post_comment_response_approval) @ThorstenKettner

Comment: I updated my main query, so you can check. Thanks @ThorstenKettner

Comment: And added post_comment_response_approval table view just to make it more understandable. @ThorstenKettner